# How to apply different operations to different columns of a matrix?

Tags: python

I have a nested list as a matrix. To each column's item of it I need to apply the same operation but one of the operation's argument depends on the column, so it's variable., and is contained in a list. What should I use for that?

Example:

```
arg_list = [1,2,3]

matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [1,3,5],
          [6,7,2],
          [1,4,2]]
```

Result of subtraction:

```
matrix = [[0,0,0],
          [0,1,2],
          [5,5,-1],
          [0,2,-1]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list of *lambda expressions* for the operations you want to carry out like:

```
operations = [lambda x:x*2,lambda x:x+1,lambda x:x//3]
```

so here we multiply the first column by two, we increment the second column and we divide the third column by three.

Now we can use the following list comprehension to generate a new matrix:

```
new_matrix = [[f(x) for f,x in zip(operations,row)] for row in matrix]
```

Say your matrix is:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [1,3,5],
          [6,7,2],
          [1,4,2]]
```

then the `new_matrix` is:

```
>>> [[f(x) for f,x in zip(operations,row)] for row in matrix]
[[2, 3, 1], [2, 4, 1], [12, 8, 0], [2, 5, 0]]
```

or more syntactically:

```
new_matrix = [[2,  3, 1],
              [2,  4, 1],
              [12, 8, 0],
              [2,  5, 0]]
```

---

In case you have however a **generic function**:

```
def f(column,x):
    # ... column is the index (starting by 0)
    return column+x # an example
```

You can use enumerate:

```
new_matrix = [[f(col,x) for col,x in enumerate(row)] for row in matrix]
```

In your case you can thus write:

```
def f(column,x):
    return x-arg_list[column]
```

Comment: @Giperboloid: that problem is adressed in the second part of the answer where a generic `f` is used that is given the column index.

Comment: Great, but how should I iterate x as an element of map in that expression?

Comment: What do you mean with an element of map? `x` is an element in your matrix.

Comment: Ok. I have a matrix and I have a map with values that corresponds to each column of the matrix. I need to perform the same operation to each element of the column with using a concrete element of the map as the second argument of the operation.

Comment: @Giperboloid: is it possible to give an example in your question. Right now it is a bit unclear what you want.

Comment: @Giperboloid: see updated answer. If you run it with that `f`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The example that you have added is either highly misleading or illustrates an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

For that specific case, you are indeed doing a vectorized or row operation (not sure on its canonical *correct* name). The most readable and efficient way, under numerical computation scenarios, would be to use the `numpy` module and exploit it:

```
import numpy as np

arg_list = np.array([1,2,3])

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],
                   [1,3,5],
                   [6,7,2],
                   [1,4,2]])

result = matrix - arg_list
```

The result is the expected matrix:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  5, -1],
       [ 0,  2, -1]])
```

---

DISCLAIMER: I am **not** answering to the original question. I am providing the sensible approach for the provided example, and also a bunch of typical numerical computation scenarios.

Comment: I'm aware of the existence of numpy, but for this time I was asked to make the solution by myself.

Comment: Then I do not agree with this specific teaching process. But that is outside the scope of SO.